# "Show Applications" empty after upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04.1

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I just upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04.1. It went mostly smoothly, except the "show applications" button on the dock pulls loads an empty window with no applications. And the Ubuntu Applications icon in the dock is now gone. Also some extensions are broken with gnome-3.38, in particular Workspaces_to_Dock, though I suppose that's not Ubuntu's fault.

I'm sure it's something borked down my ~/.local directory. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'd look into the extensions first. Disable them all and reboot to see whether the issue persists.